# Send half-size character to textbox in selenium

Tags: selenium, character-encoding

I'm trying to send a half-size text(Japanese) to textbox in selenium but it has problem. I have researched and found some solution, unfortunately no one work. I think the problem is encoding character. This is one of many solution I used to try:

```
ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("--lang=ja");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

This is a half-size text example:

```
ｶﾀｶﾅ
```

Any solution will be appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display non-english characters in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288551/how-do-i-display-non-english-characters-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

use UTF-8 char encoding while saving the script and then try again.